# How do I set up a Sinatra app under Apache with Passenger?

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra, passenger, rack

Let's say I have the simplest single-file Sinatra app. The [hello world](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) on their homepage will do. I want to run it under Apache with Phusion Passenger, AKA mod_rails.

- What directory structure do I need?
- What do I have to put in the vhost conf file?
- I understand I need a rackup file. What goes in it and why?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

#### Basic directory structure:

```
app
|-- config.ru         # <- rackup file
|-- hello-app.rb      # <- your application
|-- public/           # <- static public files (passenger needs this)
`-- tmp/              
    `-- restart.txt   # <- touch this file to restart app
```

#### Virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName    app.example.com
  DocumentRoot  /path/to/app/public
  <Directory    /path/to/app/public>
    Order       allow,deny
    Allow       from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

#### config.ru

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require './hello-app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

#### hello-app.rb (sample application):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'rubygems' # for ruby 1.8
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

`restart.txt` is empty.

---

#### Mildly useful links:

- [Heroku rack documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/rack#sinatra)
- [Phusion Passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_rackup_specifications_for_various_web_frameworks)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing, but I have an existing virtual host config. There is documentation at their site, but following that exactly, leads to an error saying:

Answer (score 2):

Example vhost file for rack app with passenger:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName   server.local
 ServerAlias  *.server.local
 DocumentRoot /dir/public
 RackEnv      development
 <Directory /dir/public>
 Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Example Config.ru:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot.rb', __FILE__)
use Rack::Middleware
run Rack::Cascade.new([array])
```

Comment: what's boot.rb and Cascade in your config.ru?