# How do I deploy sinatra to an aws ec2 ubuntu server?

Tags: ruby, apache, nginx, sinatra, web-deployment

I know how to install apache or nginx to an ubuntu server on aws. My experience is usually with php applications where I create a virtualhost and point it towards the path of my application's index.php

I would assume since Sinatra is a rack based applications, I would need to point a virtual host to the config.ru file in my application. *Is that correct?*

But then how would I keep the application running continuously *without my console*?

Could someone please explain how to setup a Sinatra deployment on either apache or nginx? I can't find any authoritative information on the web about this.

Comment: `screen` can be used to run a console process without continuously login. Not familiar with rack, but are you trying to use nginx as a `reverse proxy`?

Comment: I hope the answer listed in this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371208/how-to-setup-a-sinatra-app-under-apache-with-passenger) will help you.

Comment: What is screen exactly? never heard of it

Comment: [GNU screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) is a terminal multiplexer. In other words, it allows you to access multiple terminal sessions within a single terminal window. You can set up a screen session to run independently from a terminal as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Linode library is a good source for these types of things: [Sinatra Framework and nginx on Debian 6](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/sinatra/debian-6-squeeze)

That guide is for Debian but you should be able to follow the same steps on Ubuntu.